# Travelling around Europe for two years and looking for suitable phone / data service

Tags: europe, data-plans, mobile-operators

We are living in Australia but heading to Europe to campervan around for about two years.  I am looking for suitable phone/data or data only packages that won't cost an arm and a leg.  We are expecting to free camp quite a bit so won't be near WiFi hotspots. Coverage would need to be all over continental Europe as well as the UK.

We won't have a residential address over there which might make it hard to sign up with many of the providers or maybe this isn't a problem?

We have an Iphone 6 and an Iphone 5 as well as a small WiFi device which we can put other SIM cards into.  We would want to be able to tether to our computers from the phones.  If we could find up around 500MB /day of data that would be good.  Phone calls would not be made very often and could be over Skype phone service.

Thanks for any assistance.

Alan

Comment: It's going to take you at *least* two years of looking to find a plan like that :)

Comment: I presume you've already considered any limitations that may exist on your ability to spend time in the countries you'll be visiting.

Comment: When? Roaming fees will soon be abolished, which probably means European cellphone plans will be completely overhauled.

Comment: Thanks phoog - I have an EU passport and my wife is on an NZ passport so under EU Directive 2004/38 we both have the right to travel around Europe, including the Schengen area as much as we want provided we stay <90 days in any country.  All we need are passports/marriage cert.  There is a lot of misinformation around about this. This directive gives EU citizens and their family right of free movement around all member states. Any ideas about phone/data plans.  I had this suggested which at around 4.7 Euros/day for 1 GB/day of data http://hippocketwifi.com/en/pocket-wifi-europe-rental/